# custom webform time and date elements id's

Tags: 8, theming, webforms

Using webform, I have two "Date/time" elements with popup date and timepickers enabled. I have a jQuery script to calculate and display detailed time difference between the values (date and time) entered in the two elements fields and for that I use those elements' id's several times.

My question is:
I like to have custom id's one for each date and time element's field. Drupal/Webform automatically assign long ids like e.g. `#edit-leaving-time-time` for the time filed and `#edit-leaving-time-date` for the date field.
That's for the first Date/Time element. And likewise, there's  `#edit-returning-time-time` for the time filed and `#edit-returning-time-date` for the second Date/Time element.

The option in "**Element custom attributes (YAML)**" (*accessed from the webform element Advanced tab on editing*) to add a new id affects the whole Date/Time element's **both** date and time while I need to have unique id for each (one for the date and another for the time) to use in my jQuery script.

I see on twig debugging that those elements are controlled by the file `\web\core\themes\classy\templates\form\input.html.twig` but when I opened it, I only found this line and so I couldn't make any sense to where to go from there.

```
<input{{ attributes }} />{{ children }}
```

Although everything is working fine now and my question is more about "cosmetic" thing than functionality, I still love to learn if there's any way to do it without having to write a custom module or so since I still have no experience in that.

Thanks so much for any insightful ideas you may have.

Comment: Question indeed is: Why? You can target them easily with just the parent's IDs and their classes. You could start with implementing `hook_preprocess_input` from your theme, but I doubt you'll have a marker to identify them uniquely. So you'd first need to add them a unique enough attribute from `hook_form_alter` first, probably.

Comment: @leymannx thanks for your help but it seems I still need a lot of learning and, unless I can have a practical example or step by step how-to info to mimic I'll leave this for now till I grab enough concept of what you mentioned and now focus on the more important ones like my other webform question  https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/282349/how-can-i-apply-my-own-form-api-states-to-an-existing-webform