# Why isn't my custom Form API #states applied in my webform yaml editor working?

Tags: 8, webforms

I have the need to set visibility state of a checkbox option in one question (**Table checkbox select**) based on the value of another checkbox in the ***same table***. I also have other scenarios where I would need same functionality but across different questions in the same webform.

I know I can easily do it between two different questions ( 2 different elements) with the built-in conditional logic UI in webform but no such UI option for my case now (afaik) so I'm trying to set it via the custom one and this is my first time with form states and custom condition in webform so I appreciate your kind help so greatly.

I went through trials and errors and the code wasn't being saved till I, thanks to @jrockowitz 's tip, learnt that I was using php code where I need to use yaml code since I'm using the yaml source editor (shown in the screenshot below). When I fixed that, my custom code would save and it reflects as entered in the webform source yaml. However, the custom condition is still not working as expected and I'm still not sure why.

I'm adding the code in the Edit source box accessible via clicking its link on the form "Conditions" tab.

I got the selectors for the involved question options from the "Available selectors" list by clicking on the "Help" link under "Learn more about Drupal's Form API #states." on the "Conditional Logic" for the element editing tab in my webform.

This is a sample full yaml code for the form with a sample question and what I want to achieve but not yet working:

```
some_question:
  '#type': tableselect
  '#title': 'some question'
  '#options':
    q1: 'q1 (hide if q2 is checked)'
    q2: 'q2 (hide if q1 is checked)'
    q3: q3
    q4: q4
    q5: q5
    q6: q6
    q7: q7
  '#states':
    ':input[name="some_question[q2]"]':
      invisible:
        ':input[name="some_question[q1]"]':
          checked: true
    ':input[name="some_question[q1]"]':
      invisible:
        ':input[name="some_question[q2]"]':
          checked: true
```

What am I missing here ?!

- For those who maybe aren't familiar with the UI edit source, this is a link with info and screenshots : https://www.drupal.org/node/3012686
- **Note:** As per @leymannx 's kind advice, I re-wrote the whole question to rid it of my dump of updates with my trials and errors. I hope it's now cleaner, clearer and more worthy of up-votes :)

Comment: Where are you putting that code exactly? What function? What file? You don't need to recreate the element but only the `#states` array like this: `$form['foo_bar']['#states'] = [ /** whatever */ ]`. Do you know of Devel's  submodule Kint for debugging? And that you can dump the form with `ksm($form)` for inspection to get to know the right element names?

Comment: @leymannx thanks so much for your help. I answered your questions in the post edits and added updates on what I've done so far. I'm learning by trial & error. I'm not a developer and  D8 has gone way far for lone drupalers like me having to learn so many things deep down to get things done. So I really appreciate any light you shed on what more to do to solve this considering I'm trying to use the webform's own built-in custom condition source editor and not trying to write a custom module or so. That's an intensive one on my plate waiting for time to be able to digest . Thanks so much ++

Comment: @leymannx with regards getting " to know the right element names" , I got them from the built-in Webform's list via clicking on the "help" link at the bottom like in the screenshot. I did enable Kint though and added it to the webform-submission-form.html.twig and I have it now on every webform page but I am not sure what to look for in it since all the info I already know them from elsewhere! Please let me know what to look for in kent that's not available already from my mentioned resources. And what's wrong with the codes I posted! Cheers

Comment: Your custom #states code must be in YAML (not PHP).  The best way to get started with YAML is to create a few conditions via the UI and then switch to the source module.

Comment: @jrockowitz thanks so much for the tip. That's what I needed to hear. I tried that and it's now saving without php errors but it doesn't seem to be functioning though! I update my OP shortly with what I did. Many thanks +++

Comment: @leymannx , I'm wondering why after being up-voted it's now downvoted! I'm new here and I never ask for support unless I'd exhausted all my abilities and research. I think it's clear that I did my best to show that in my OP and I don't understand why the down vote! I personally think webform, a great drupal asset, has lots of hidden potentials that many like me have yet to discover and my OP can be of help to many including learning from  my mistakes. I appreciate your kind support from the start and am grateful for the things I learnt from you. Please kindly enlighten me, not frustrate me!!!

Comment: Unfortunately this question gets broader and broader and broader; too broad. Maybe you can rewrite it to reflect just where you are standing currently and dump most of your trial and errors. Also I found quite lots of info in Webform's changelog and issue queue which you might want to have a look at.

Comment: @leymannx thanks for your response although I find posting here very frustrating and off-putting! Rules here make it look like one needs a degree in how to walk in this landmine without being fired. I tried my best to be as clear as I could and to keep my post updated so any helper would be on track with me but that seems to have backfired at me. I didn't ask here till I exhausted all my research and found nothing online. I will re-go through all the issues queue maybe I missed something. Had I had jrockowitz's tip earlier, that would've saved most/all the edits here. I'll rewrite and clean it

Comment: @leymannx I re-wrote it fully and I hope it's a pass now :)

Comment: Based on your example it looks like you are trying to conditionally hide a single likert questions (i.e. some_question[q1]) based on the value from another question. This is not possible via the UI.  You will most likely have to write custom webform element.

Comment: @jrockowitz – Wouldn't it work with YAML code similar to the one in the following issue: https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/2995525

Comment: @Adam888 – I remember it being frustrating in the beginning. It's a lot about curating questions. You need to know what you want. Then it gets easier. But yeah, this is open source. We are all volunteers here. And actually it's working much better here as in other Stacks.

Comment: There needs to be a more concrete basic example for everyone to understand what is being targeted with the conditional logic.

Comment: @jrockowitz the example here's checkboxes type element with 20 options and unlimited allowed number of values where I need to control visibility of one or two options each based on another option (checkbox value) under the same element. But yes, I do have likert type questions and tried it on with same fail unfortunately! Sad to hear it's not doable the way I hoped and it seems I either have to learn how to write custom element like you suggest or find a way around it. I hope I made the right choice in WF vs LimeSurvey esp. I shall have many conditionals across elements. Much grateful, thanks

Comment: You might be able to use a form alter hook to add the needed #states.

Answer (score 0):

For the simple case where Question 2 is shown only if Question 1 is left unchecked, your YAML doesn't look right to me. If you're editing YAML in the conditions tab for the Question 2 checkbox, then just the last 3 lines should suffice:

```
invisible:
  ':input[name="some_question[q1]"]':
    checked: true
```

I don't think you want the `"#states"` key to be in there anywhere, nor do you want to include any selector information for Question 2.

That's if the YAML is part of Question 2's Condition source. If on the other hand the YAML you're showing is part of the *form's* source, then it should probably look something like this:

```
q2:
  '#type': checkbox
  '#title': 'Question 2'
  '#states':
    invisible:
      ':input[name="some_question[q1]"]':
        checked: true
```

Note that the `#states` key is shown here, but only once - we're omitting 2 out of 3 of the same lines as above.

Comment: thanks for your reply and sorry for being months late. I had personal circumstances and had to be away. I updated the question with a sample yaml code for the whole form so it's clearer what type of questions I meant. I think your answer wasn't meant for the case I have (options/checkboxes in the same question). Please correct me if I'm wrong. Cheers